# Best strategies for Synchronizing Application to Robotscripts across different browsers and platforms

Tags: robotframework

I have to run the Testsuites across Windows (Chrome, Firefox, and IE) and macOS (Safari and Chrome).

Wanted to implement best strategies to Synchronize AUT with Robot test scripts  while testing around Cross browser and Cross platform.

Somehow felt handling Safari browser on macOS is bit challenging. How best I try add some wait but still fail for each run with some 'ElementNotVisibleException'.

However Chrome on Mac OS is quite okay when the same is tested on Windows machine.

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated on best handling mechanisms for Safari on Mac OS.

Thanking in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use Wait Until Element is Visible Keyword from selenium2Librray  from robot framework. the best way is to do it on safari is try executing the scenario manually first and note the maximum time it takes to load the webElement. Once you note down the time, put this time as you max timeout. Below is one example

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible  ${mention_locator_here}  timeout=${element_timeout_in_seconds}
```

You can explore those options [Here](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Wait%20Until%20Element%20Is%20Visible)